# surgery: save mother or baby?

Tags: internal-consistency, medicine, medical

At some point in the story of my game, a pregnant woman gets into an accident or suffers from a disease or whatever (choose what fits most) and lands in the hospital. The woman, barely conscious, has to make a decision:

- She sacrifices the baby to save herself for sure (there's a very slim chance she will die from this)

-or-

- She risks a surgery that will save the baby but can either save her or kill her, with the latter being more likely, unfortunately.

I know this setup is very specific, but is there some medical condition, or a way someone can get into an accident that would lead into such a situation? Is a situation like that even possible?

Comment: Thanks for the senseless downvote btw, always nice to see.

Comment: I would say if it is someone that is vital to the plot sacrifice the baby but if it is not then save the baby. Btw, this question is kind of unsuited for worldbuilding.

- **Do not apply this to real life**

Comment: This has  nothing to do with Worldbuilding.

Comment: Senseless upvote is always nice, too.

Comment: Double posts are always nice as well. With a "senseless" upvote, you know you didn't do anything wrong (if there's something that bothers the upvoter, he will probably make a comment). When someone just downvotes and doesn't give any explanation, that doesn't give me a way to improve my questions, does it? And how is this not worldbuilding? If my story is based on our world, why wouldn't I want to make sure the things that happen there can actually happen in real life? I don't want to make up a bullshit excuse for why something like that happened.

Comment: I know I was confused when reading your question.  If you would make it more obvious that you require a plausible reason for the situation described rather than a persons opinion on which to save it would help.

Comment: @noClue a downvote generally indicates that someone does not find your question being up to one of many standards either personal or objective, while the latter is preferred the former will and does happen. Getting an explanation of why a question has been downvoted is often very helpful but you cannot force someone to give you a competent feedback and neither are they obliged to it. Also by criticizing an uncommented downvote you might further antagonize the voter, making a helpful feedback even less likely

Comment: Oh I know - I don't expect this to change, just wanted to express my displeasure. I know it's pointless to rant about it, but it's still frustrating to get a downvote with no explanation. As for making the question more obvious... the last paragraph makes it very clear what I'm asking for. I don't really see how someone can misunderstand what the question is about, unless someone just skims through my pathetically small question (I'm sorry, but that's on you).

Comment: When a downvote is given without a comment, you can generally assume it is for some variation of the canonical downvote reason (seen by hovering over the downvote button): *"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"*

Comment: I think that people are distracted by the first paragraph here and considering the ethical aspect of this question.  The actual question is relating to what situations could lead up to this decision.  For me, the question is **too broad** since there could be any amount of diseases or injuries to qualify.  Surely the cause of this disease/injury would be a fairly significant plot point in this story.

Comment: @noClue - Your question title also needs editing to make the question clearer in purpose.  The question title should really summarize the question and not lead readers into answering something else.

Comment: This feels like a specific plot point question rather than a worldbuilding question. You might be better off asking it on a medical or similar board. For what it's worth though I know that things like this happen, generally due to complications in birth and loss of blood etc. There was the case of a woman who died in Ireland recently because the doctors refused to abort the baby that was killing her and as a result both died.

Comment: This is a hypothetical ethical dilemma not world building, anyhow I think it is morally wrong to judge who should survive the labor complication by applying game theory so I suggest leaving everything to destiny, the will of god a.k.a coin toss!

Answer (score 3):

### Cancer

While such an accident is quite unlikely, some serious diseases only have cures that an unborn child will hardly survive.

Cancer being the most obvious example.

Comment: +1 on this. Ovarian, cervical or pancreatic cancer that shows some signs of spreading. Radiation therapy and chemo is more or less out of the question if you are pregnant, especially if early in the pregnancy. And the author can tailor the  scenario so that waiting six months pretty much guarantees the spread of the cancer and a much more difficult struggle to combat it.

Answer (score 2):

Preeclampsia is a condition which causes high blood pressure in pregnant woman without any prior history of it.  This is very dangerous for the mother and the baby and often leads to difficult choices that have to be made. Here is a link that might be helpful for you: http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/preeclampsia/basics/complications/con-20031644

Comment: HELLP syndrome would probably make a better setting as an example.  There the trade would be keeping the baby a little longer so it is more viable, versus extracting the baby immediately and providing immediate relief to the mother.  HELLP is reasonably common (~0.25 to 0.5%).